# Nativescript and Angular code split, maven build failing

Tags: angular, nativescript, code-splitting, nativescript-angular

We are developing a project that sharing the code between nativescript and web. We used nativescript schematics to create the project (Java, Ng, {N}).

Right now, we are running an issue that when we run Maven to build the web project, we get an error while compiling .tns file. From [Nativescript code split page](https://docs.nativescript.org/code-sharing/code-splitting) we thought, excluding .tns at tsconfig.app.json file should do the job, but seems not

In tsconfig.app.json file, we have the following

```
"exclude": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.ns.ts",
    "**/*.tns.ts",
    "**/*.android.ts",
    "**/*.ios.ts"
  ]
```

example for component that share the code

```
about.component.ts
about.component.css
about.component.tns.html
about.component.html
```

example for component that is only mobile

```
welcome.componenet.tns.ts
welcome.componenet.tns.html
welcome.componenet.common.tns.css
welcome.componenet.ios.css
welcome.componenet.android.css
```

We are not sure why maven compiling .tns files and complaining about all tns-code-modules lib. Also platform dependents files like .ios.css and .android.css files, maven complain about couldn't resolve "welcome.component.css"

What we should do to exclude files like .tns and if we want to exclude entire folder like pre-login folder which is only mobile folder